# ¿Como pongo el file path en python?

Tags: python

Muy buenas. Estoy tratando de ejecutar este código pero no se como poner el file path para que se pueda ejecutar el programa.

```
import string
# Crear un programa que lea un archivo de texto y cuente la frecuencia de cada palabra en él.
# El programa debería ignorar las mayúsculas y minúsculas y eliminar los signos de puntuación. 
# Una vez que el programa ha contado la frecuencia de cada palabra, debería imprimir las palabras en orden de frecuencia decreciente.

def leer_archivo(file_path):
    # Abrir el archivo en modo lectura
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        # Leer el contenido del archivo
        text = f.read()
    # Eliminar los signos de puntuación y convertir a minúsculas
    text = text.translate(text.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)).lower()
    # Crear un diccionario para contar la frecuencia de cada palabra
    word_freq = {}
    # Dividimos el texto en palabras
    for word in text.split():
        if word in word_freq:
            word_freq[word] += 1
        else:
            word_freq[word] = 1
    # Ordenamos las palabras por frecuencia       
    ordenar_palab = sorted(word_freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # Imprimimos las palabras y sus frecuencias
    for word, freq in ordenar_palab:
        print(f"{word}: {freq}")

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    leer_archivo(file_path=EJERCICIOS PYTHON/)
```

Como veis estoy tratando de ejecutar el código pero el archivo que tengo creado en la carpeta no me lo reconoce. ¿Sabéis de qué manera puedo ejecutarlo?

Comment: Tal como lo estas colocando te debe dar error de sintaxis, las rutas a archivos también son strings as8 que debes cocerlo como uno. Para hacerte las cosas más fácil python tiene el módulo `pathlib` para que puedas trabajar con rutas

Comment: Un ejemplo: `leer_archivo("C:\archivo.txt")`

Comment: si puedes mostrar como es el archivo que deceas leer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El bloque

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    leer_archivo(file_path=EJERCICIOS PYTHON/)
```

Es el que ejecuta la función cuando se envía el archivo directamente a Python (a diferencia, por ejemplo, de importarlo). La expresión `file_path=EJERCICIOS PYTHON/` es la que indica cuál debe ser el archivo. Este parámetro debe ser una cadena de texto que represente la ruta del archivo.

La expresión que tienes, sin comillas, no es válida en Python: Python supondría que `EJERCICIOS` es una variable, pero tener un espacio seguido con otro "nombre de variable" (`PYTHON` en este caso,) no tiene sentido en la sintaxis de Python, y menos seguido de la diagonal (que se usa para la división).

Como sugiere Mateo, debes poner la ruta del archivo entre comillas. Determina cómo se llama, y escríbelo entre comillas. Si el archivo está en la misma carpeta que el `.py`, puedes escribir sólo el nombre (ejemplo: `"archivo.txt"`), y, si no, debes poner la ruta completa (ejemplo en Windows: `"C:∖carpeta∖archivo.txt"`, ejemplo en Linux/Mac: `"/home/usuario/archivo/.txt"`).

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias!!